# identifying substituted type of Collection using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections

I'm writing a little library for automatic generation of test data. It uses reflection to be able to create a randomized instance of any class. I ran in to issues when one of the classes had a field of type `List<T>`. How do i find out the type of T?

playing around in IntelliJ's "evaluate expression" console, i came up with the following:

```
 private Class getGenericType(Field field){
        return ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass();
    }
```

which in seemed to work when evaluating in the popup console, but when I put it into the code and run, i get

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)
```

any ideas? am I even on the right path?

Comment: The shown code doesn’t call `newInstance`. But assuming that you are calling `newInstance` on the result of the shown method, that’s expected behavior, as that method doesn’t return the type argument, but the result calling `getClass()` on the type argument, which leads to results like `Class.class`, or an implementation type of `ParameterizedType`, `TypeVariable`, or such alike. The actual type argument is what you had before calling `getClass()`, which is a `Type` that might be a `Class` but doesn’t have to.

Comment: this is not going to be easy. a `Type` can be : a `Class` (and it can be an array or a plain class from here), a `TypeVariable`, a `ParameterizedType`, a `GenericArrayType` or a `WildcardType`. If that is not complicated enough, even the `Class` might not be a type that can be instantiated at all (an interface) or one that does not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element of the array is already a Class instance so you can do this

```
 private Class getGenericType(Field field){
    return (Class)((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
 }
```

**Edit**: This would only work assuming the generic type is a concrete non-generic type as in `List<String>`. For more complex cases you will have to check if the type is one that can be instantiated. See comments.

Comment: It’s not guaranteed to be a `Class`. It might be a type variable, parameterized type, wildcard type, etc.

Comment: Right, I guess this covers just the case List<Object>, but not List<List<Object>> (and further nested generic types). I guess in all the other cases it would not be possible to create an instance?

Comment: Even if the type parameter is a `Class`, there is no guaranty that it can be instantiated. It might be an interface, annotation, or enum type, or an abstract class or a class with no accessible default constructor…